# jQuery causing page to fail at a fundamental level... Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function that is not seen as being in scope as long as I have a reference to jQuery is defined. If I comment that reference the call to the function works. I have other pages that reference jQuery the same way and they work. Its really frustrating. What gives?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Anything</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
        alert('This works')
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
text
<script type="text/javascript">
    test();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" />
```

... do this:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`script` tag is weird. :)

Comment: `script` blocks cannot be self closing. +1

Comment: I really like JavaScript as a language. jQuery is cool too. Things like this... That solved it though.

Answer (score 3):

Does doctype HTML support closing script as a short tag? I would try `<script src...></script>`.